# Convert .doc resource file Word.Document object

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, resources

in my VB.NET project I included a word document called `PrintOut.doc` as resource (`My.Resources.DocumentPrintOut`)

Now the question is how can I convert this resource to a `Word.Document` object so that it is possible to open and modify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store the Word Doc file into your resources as a binary blob, you should automatically have a function created in your resources.designer.vb file, something like this:

```
Friend ReadOnly Property MyFile() As Byte()
    Get
        Dim obj As Object = ResourceManager.GetObject("MyFile", resourceCulture)
        Return CType(obj,Byte())
    End Get
End Property
```

that will return a byte array containing the complete contents of the file. Just write that Byte array to a file and name it your original DOC filename, and you can then open it via word or do whatever you need to with it.